# REST - Journey with DE as trigger

Tags: journeybuilder, dataextensions, json, rest, post

In my app i have a api call which creates a new dataextension through the soap API. When that is done I want to create a new journey with that DE as a starting source. I'm able to create the journey, but cant figure out how to get the newly created DE as a starting source. How should the json body look?

```
{
    key: journeyName,
    name: journeyName,
    workflowApiVersion: 1,
    triggers: [
      {
        key: DEKey,
        type: "DataExtension",
        name: "Starting point for the journey",
        eventDefinitionKey: DEKey + "_eventDefinition",
        arguments: {},
        configurationArguments: {
          applicationExtensionKey: DEKey,
          defaults: {
            loadDataExtension: true
          }
        },
        metaData: {
          isConfigured: true
        }
      }
    ],
    goals: [],
    activities: []
  }
```

A POST request with this body to /interaction/v1/interactions creates a journey but not with the dataextension as a starting source, and I am pretty blank on how to move forward as I cant find any good documentation on this.

Comment: Have you created the EventDefinition using the API prior to trying to create the JB Interaction?

Comment: I looked into it, but seemingly doing something wrong.

This is an example body of what Ive been trying:
{
    "type": "Event",
    "name": "Demo",
    "description": "New event definition",
    "mode": "Production",
    "eventDefinitionKey": "testDefKey",
    "dataExtensionId": DEkey,
    "iconUrl": "/events/images/icon_journeyBuilder-event-api-blue.svg",
    "isVisibleInPicker": true,
    "category": "Event"
}

Then when creating the journey I use those values in the first object in the triggers array. Like "eventDefinitionKey": "testDefKey"

Comment: Im new to this forum, but see the formatting became a bit weird and Im not allowed to write more characters. So i cropped the example a bit. Sorry :D

Comment: You need to make an API call to create the EventDefinition before you can reference it in your API call that creates the new interaction/journey.